# how to save pdf from uiwebview in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uiwebview, ibooks

i want to save pdf to ibook from UIWebView in the app, the html in UIWebView can be multi page.
i try using

```
NSString *page = [self.lowWebview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.outerHTML"];
NSString *path = [self exportHTMLContentToPDF:page];

NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:targetURL];

if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-books:"]])
{
    [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"iBooks installed");

} else {

    NSLog(@"iBooks not installed");

}
```

exportHTMLContentToPDF:

```
CustomPrintPageRenderer *printPageRenderer = [[CustomPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];

UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter *printFormatter = [[UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter alloc] initWithMarkupText:HTMLContent];

[printPageRenderer addPrintFormatter:printFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];//.addPrintFormatter(printFormatter, startingAtPageAtIndex: 0)

NSData *pdfData = [self drawPDFUsingPrintPageRenderer:printPageRenderer];

NSString *docDirPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *fileName = [docDirPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ticket.pdf"];

[pdfData writeToFile:fileName atomically:true];//.writeToFile(fileName, atomically: true)

NSLog(@"%@", fileName);
return fileName;
```

the problem is **exportHTMLContentToPDF** create just one page if UIWebView contain multiple page, and some time the output format is not well print in pdf

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**Create PDF from any Microsoft Document loaded in UIWebview**

```
#define kPaperSizeA4 CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8)
```

First of all implement UIPrintPageRenderer protocol

```
@interface UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)

- (NSData*) printToPDF;

@end

@implementation UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)

- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, self.paperRect, nil );
    [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];
    CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        [self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
    }
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    return pdfData;
}
@end
```

Then, call below method after document finished loading in `UIWebView`

```
-(void)createPDF:(UIWebView *)webView {

UIPrintPageRenderer *render = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
[render addPrintFormatter:webView.viewPrintFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];

float padding = 10.0f;
CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, kPaperSizeA4.width, kPaperSizeA4.height);
CGRect printableRect = CGRectMake(padding, padding, kPaperSizeA4.width-(padding * 2), kPaperSizeA4.height-(padding * 2));

[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:paperRect] forKey:@"paperRect"];
[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:printableRect] forKey:@"printableRect"];

NSData *pdfData = [render printToPDF];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    if (pdfData) {
        [pdfData writeToFile:directoryPath atomically: YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"PDF couldnot be created");
    }
});}
```

Excerpted from [PDF Creation in iOS - Create PDF from any Microsoft Document loaded in UIWebview](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006210548/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/2416/pdf-creation-in-ios/28437/create-pdf-from-any-microsoft-document-loaded-in-uiwebview#t=201710062105487361045). The original author was [Mansi Panchal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1309698/mansi-panchal). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/28437). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 2416 and example ID: 28437.

Comment: the app hang in this line "[self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];" and no error or crash show in xcode, just hanging

Answer (score 1):

```
#define kPaperSizeA4 CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8)
```

First of all implement UIPrintPageRenderer protocol

```
@interface UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)
- (NSData*) printToPDF;
@end
@implementation UIPrintPageRenderer (PDF)
- (NSData*) printToPDF
{
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, self.paperRect, nil );
    [self prepareForDrawingPages: NSMakeRange(0, self.numberOfPages)];
    CGRect bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < self.numberOfPages ; i++ )
    {
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
[self drawPageAtIndex: i inRect: bounds];
    }
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
return pdfData;
}
@end
```

Then, call below method after document finished loading in UIWebView

```
-(void)createPDF:(UIWebView *)webView {
UIPrintPageRenderer *render = [[UIPrintPageRenderer alloc] init];
[render addPrintFormatter:webView.viewPrintFormatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];
float padding = 10.0f;
CGRect paperRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, kPaperSizeA4.width, kPaperSizeA4.height);
CGRect printableRect = CGRectMake(padding, padding, kPaperSizeA4.width-(padding * 2), kPaperSizeA4.height-(padding * 2));
[render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:paperRect] forKey:@"paperRect"];
 [render setValue:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:printableRect] forKey:@"printableRect"];
NSData *pdfData = [render printToPDF];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
if (pdfData) {
        [pdfData writeToFile:directoryPath atomically: YES];
}
else
{
        NSLog(@"PDF couldnot be created");
} });}
```

[image]

Ref: https://medium.com/@javedmultani16/create-pdf-from-any-microsoft-document-loaded-in-uiwebview-in-ios-15229671060b

Answer (score 0):

This may help with quality and multi-page issues : 
https://coderwall.com/p/gssuka/rendering-html-pdf-report-for-printing-from-uiwebview